# Low voltage control for actuation analysis. How to do it?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, voltage, circuit-design, polarity

I would like to create a circuit, where I can modify the output voltage between -5V to +5V such I can customize values between this interval, like -3.2 V to +1.4V or -1.0V to +1.0V etc. Is it possible with an 555 timer IC?

My project would be to create an automated circuit for actuation analysis, i.e. switching from +1.5V to -1.5V with a time period of 5 seconds for several tenths of cycles. I saw Arduino can be easily programmed, but as I know Arduino modules cannot produce negative voltages, maybe with an L298N DC Motor interface, but I do not know how to start this.

So after all I need to generate a bidirectional square wave with adjustable frequency.
Could you give me some advice about this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Start with a bi-directional supply voltage i.e. a dual supply of +V and -V. Then learn about op-amp signal inverters. Then learn about op-amp clamp circuits and you're nearly there. Don't pursue any design that uses the L298 and try to stay away from [666](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_beast) timers in this application.

Comment: What will the output of this circuit be used for ? What will be connected to the output terminals ? What do you mean by customise ? What is the input to this circuit and how does it determine what the output voltage will be ?

Comment: The output of the circuit will be connected to an electrochemically synthesized electroactive polymer sheet, which is capable of bending bidirectionally depending on the voltage polarity. The input will be either an DC Power Supply (Keithley) or the USB port on my PC. I like to solve this as easily as possible. I would like to analyze how many bending periods the sample can withstand without being there. So automatically switching between +1V and -1V for several periods.

Comment: You also mentioned  "*-3.2 V to +1.4V*". In that example, Does A) the voltage switch between -3.2V and +1.4V on one terminal while other terminal is 0V or b) is the total load experiencing a swing of 2*(1.4 - -3.2)V ?) per cycle ?

Comment: Those values are just examples only, but my purpose here is applying a positive voltage (mainly in the range of +0.5 - 2V) for several seconds to the sample, then switch it to the negative polarity of the same value. So as you mentioned as method A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with an 555 CMOS timer IC, but only for light loads. The lower frequencies may require a higher C2 value.
[image: 555negative]

Comment: As I see it, those pulses has a length of milliseconds? Is it possible to extend to a few seconds, because the sample has a low reaction time as it reaches its max elongation from the initial state. So C2 is 10 microFarad on your picture. Higher the value of C2 means longer pulse length? I mean applying a 470 microFarad, or even higher, I can increase the length indefinitely, or it has its limits?

Comment: The frequency can be adjusted with a combination of C1 and R1. It can be a cycle time of several seconds, then a larger C2 is required for the square negative output signal.

Comment: @ Ryksa A few [seconds](https://imgur.com/a/oang7S0) version.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I see from the schematic, I only need the upper (+- Uout) output to connect to the oscilloscope to analyze, then to the sample. The +Uout and -Uout is optional elements in the system.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Two more thing is not clear to me. Are the Schottky diodes needed, if I will operate the circuit in low-frequency mode? Also the "Trigger" pin is only connected to the ground without an external signal generator applied?

Comment: Schottky diodes are needed due to the small voltage drop. The Trigger pin is tied to C1 for a 50% duty cycle.

Comment: If you have an external generator, you don't need the 555. U + will be the output of the external generator. You need two diodes, two resistors and C2.

Comment: I specify: I have a DC Power Supply Module 3.3V/5.0V and a Keithly Source Meter. As I can comprehend from the schem. the supply voltage is connected to the Vdd and to the Reset, so these instrument's output should be connected to there? Sorry for the many questions. :)

Comment: Yes, the supply voltage of the CMOS 555 can be 3 ... 15V. It generates greater AC voltage with a higher supply voltage.